# Can exterior exhaust vents be stacked on top of one another?

Tags: hvac, ventilation

A bathroom toilet room already has an exterior exhaust vent as seen in the pic. Is it within code and ok to install another, and identical, exhaust vent directly below the current one.

The Master Bath needs another exhaust fan and this is the only place feasible to exhaust this soon to be installed fan.

**Question**

[image: Current Exhaust Vent]

Comment: Ate you sure there is room to stack them? I suspect the need to be side by side.

Comment: Sure, the stud bay is clear and the exterior, as you can see is clear as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's acceptable by code. Make sure both have a backdraft damper (flap).

Answer (score 0):

I have only seen them side by side, but close together still. Code does not want an intake too close to an exhaust vent.

Answer (score 0):

Bath exhaust vents next to each other is fine with flaps.  On the other hand, combustible air from gas appliances have very specific rules.  For example, at least 36" from any makeup air vents is required for some situations..  Always consult appliance documentation for specific guidelines.